# Aliases for user profile URLs

Tags: 7, path-aliases, users

For example, the URL http://example.com/user/20/edit/cocktail?destination=user%2F20 leads to a page with the form to add content.

I want to create an alias like bartender/add/cocktail, or
(if possible) bartender/profile/[current-loggedin-bartender-name], [current-loggedin-bartender-surname]/add/cocktail.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module might help you for your requirements...
Check it.

Comment: Thanks. I use pathauto but I have no idea how to use this module to create those kinds of aliases

Comment: You can have a look in this video.. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDx3ruLg1OQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those kinds of aliases cannot be implemented by the Pathauto module because it is difficult to add tokens into the menu settings. To help with this in the past, I used the [me aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module.

> Provides shortcut paths to current user's pages, eg user/me, blog/me, user/me/edit, tracker/me etc.

It has a Drupal 7 release which has been released on June 8, 2019. There is an issue open to port the module to Drupal 8/9: [Port Me module to Drupal 8 / 9](https://www.drupal.org/project/me/issues/3111433).

Answer (score 0):

Menu tokens is another option that looks a bit more robust than me aliases but they both now have token replacements and it is still in alpha3 as of now.

[Menu Token module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token)